# Filter two select fields based upon two options and total availability

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two select options for adults and children in my form:

```
<select name="BKG_Adult">
    <option value="1" data-price="1000">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="2000">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="3000">3</option>
    <option value="4" data-price="4000">4</option>
</select>

<select name="BKG_Child">
    <option value="0" data-price="0">0</option>
    <option value="1" data-price="500">1</option>
    <option value="2" data-price="1000">2</option>
    <option value="3" data-price="1500">3</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="dynamic_availability" name="dynamic_availability" value="4">
```

The hidden field dynamic availability is populated by an external web service on page load to give the total amount of seats available on a tour. The options are also populated on page load.

The main rule of the form is that at least one adult must travel on the tour. The remaining seats can then be made up of a combination of children and adults.

If 2 adults are selected, I need to reduce the amount of options in the child select to ensure that the user cannot select over 4 people in total. Equally, if 2 children are selected in the child select I must restrict the values in the adult select but still ensure that at least one adult is selected.

Essentially this will use the onchange event of the child and adult select fields but the complexity is filtering the options based upon the rules defined above. Of course, if the user were to reduce the number of options selected in one field, the number of options should increase in the other field so that the user can still select a maximum of 4.

Does anyone know of an example of such functionality or how this can be implemented in vanilla javascript or jquery?

Comment: To whoever down voted this question, please give your reasoning. You have no grounds to do so as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var max = $("#dynamic_availability").val(),
        $adult = $("#adult"),
        $child = $("#child");
    fillCmb($adult, 1, max);
    fillCmb($child, 0, max - 1);
    $adult.on("change", function() {
        var cant = $(this).val();
        fillCmb($child, 0, max - cant);
    });
    $child.on("change", function() {
        var cant = $(this).val();
        fillCmb($adult, 1, max - cant);
    });

    function fillCmb($cmb, min, max) {
        var val = $cmb.val();
        $cmb.empty();
        for (var i = min; i <= max; i++)
            $cmb.append("<option value=\"" + i + "\">" + i + "</option>");
        if (val)
            $cmb.val(val);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/paska/9ac1ta7u/2/

Comment: Thanks for the response but when selecting an adult value, it rests the child selection to zero. Really it should keep the value that is currently in place

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the best solution. The price for each passenger is actually stored against each option and from what I see you are dynamically creating and removing options in the select rather than showing and hiding options that are already there. This creation and removal means that the price no longer exists as a data attribute and therefore no price calculation can take place.

Comment: There is no cross-browser way to hide options in a select. The other option you have is to save each option from each select in an array when the page loads and then instead of creating a new option, you use those saved.

Comment: What about applying a class that enacts a disply:hidden on the items that are not available. Yes they are still available to select in the Dom but as we validate on the server as well anyway then this isn't really a problem.

Comment: I believe that your solution wont work on every browser (if it does in any). The only option you have is to remove the options you don't want to avoid them being shown. You always should validate on the server as well (any scenario, any solution; client side can always be modified by users). Also, for other scenarios, the right value for `display` is `none`, not `hidden`

Comment: Hi Diego, display: none is cross browser compatible. http://caniuse.com/#search=display

Comment: Yes, `display: none` is, but not for the `option` tag. See this fiddle in IE: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/8zkk8f6a/1/

Comment: This really isn't a viable option. My options are created by a razor view which appends necessary information such as pricing to the options. I've thought about using jQuery filtering as shown in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/dpxw7LhL/5/ however it doesn't seem to work

Comment: All you should modify in my solution is saving the options in an array for each combo when the document loads. Then, instead of creating a new option you can access the created option in the array using `i` as the array position.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function changeSelect(element, otherSelectValue){
    var options = element.find(option);
    for(x=0; options.length; x++){
        if((options[x].value() + value) > 4){
            options[x].remove();
        }
    }
}

$('#adult', '#child').on('change', function(){
   if(this.attr('id') === 'adult'){
       changeSelect($('#child'), this.val());
   }else{
       changeSelect($('#adult'), this.val());
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="adult" name="BKG_Adult">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<select id="child" name="BKG_Child">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```